# Why does MySQL Docker container complain that MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD env must be defined when using Docker 17.03 secrets?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker, docker-swarm, docker-secrets

I'm trying to adapt Docker's Wordpress secret example (link below) to work in my Docker Compose setup (for Drupal).

https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/#/advanced-example-use-secrets-with-a-wordpress-service

However, when the 'mysql' container is spun up, the following error is output:

> "error: database is uninitialized and password option is not specified
>   You need to specify one of MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD, MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD and MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD"

I created the secrets using the 'docker secret create' command:

```
docker secret create mysql_root_pw tmp-file-holding-root-pw.txt
docker secret create mysql_pw tmp-file-holding-pw.txt
```

After running the above, the secrets '**mysql_root_pw**' and '**mysql_pw**' now exist in the swarm environment.  Verified by doing:

```
docker secret ls
```

Here are the relevant parts from my **docker-compose.yml** file:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql/mysql-server:5.7.17 
   environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE="/run/secrets/mysql_root_pw"
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD_FILE="/run/secrets/mysql_pw"
    secrets:
      - mysql_pw
      - mysql_root_pw

secrets:
  mysql_pw:
    external: true
  mysql_root_pw:
    external: true
```

When I do "**docker stack deploy MYSTACK**", I get the error mentioned above when the 'mysql' container attempts to start.

It seems like "**MYSQL_PASSWORD_FILE**" and "**MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE**" are not standard environment variables recognized by MySQL, and it's still expecting "**MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD**" environment variable.

I'm using Docker 17.03.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Actually you gave the answer to your initial question yourself. You have any other question?

Comment: Hey, I just tested this (not exactly this - the `docker service create` from the article) and got the same errors as you see. After reading the article I saw at the end a note informing users that images need to be updated to take secrets into account. I took a look at the date the mysql image added support and found it was [Nov 22](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/commit/4dd33136c4739667a223d39b6f829beb27b235cf#diff-17ed820d5141a5e8565a0431e5385dae). My local image was older than that so I ran `docker pull mysql:latest` and got a recent image. Re-ran the command and it started :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply William. Very interesting! I just set up my host (Ubuntu 16.04) a couple of weeks ago (no Docker images pulled down), with a Docker 17.03 install, and ran "docker stack deploy ..." with the following in my docker-compose.yml file:

`services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql/mysql-server:5.7.17`

so it should have pulled down the latest 5.7.17 image as of a couple weeks ago. When I do `docker image ls` though, it shows "mysql/mysql-server" for the "REPOSITORY" but "<none>" for the "TAG". I will figure out how to pull down the specific 5.7.17 mysql image and let you know.

Comment: For some reason, the image "**mysql/mysql-server:5.7.17**" is pinned, at least for me, to this digest: "Digest: sha256:083f7ef16586208dce7275c84d7d7085e1acaf2caf2d0443e8827d191296099c". If I inspect the image (`docker inspect <IMAGE-ID>`), it says **"Created": "2017-02-16T07:06:16.474620534Z"**. I'll see if I can find the digest for the image that contains the "_FILE" secrets fix and try to pull the mysql by that digest...

Comment: William, got it working.  I was actually using the **mysql/mysql-server:5.7.17** image instead of **mysql:5.7.17**.  Your answer helped me resolve my issue, so if you re-post your above reply and add at the end "Try the 'mysql:5.7.17' image instead of 'mysql/mysql-server:5.7.17' image, as the Docker secrets enhancement may have only been added to the former.", I will mark it as the correct answer and give you credit.  Thanks again for your help.  Now I just have to figure out how to get Docker secrets working in the 'drupal' container. ;)  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You get this error if your secret is a empty string as well.  That is what happened to me, secret is mounted and service properly configured, but still fails because there is not password.